# Key-Formal-Verification with Xtext 2.25

Tags: java, eclipse, key-formal-verification

I am working on a project with formal verification with key in Java.
I am using the Eclipse Plugin for that.
Everything worked fine when I had Xtext Version 2.10.
For some reasons though, I hat to update to Xtext 2.25.
Unfortunately, I get the following error now:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2021-05-20 11:22:24.373
!MESSAGE Failed to evaluate: AndExpression [children=[WithExpression [variable=selection, children=[AndExpression [children=[<test property="isGoal" plug-in activation: eager/>]]]]]]
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: No property tester contributes a property org.key_project.keyide.ui.isGoal to type class org.eclipse.jface.text.TextSelection
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtensionManager.getProperty(TypeExtensionManager.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.AndExpression.evaluate(AndExpression.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.AndExpression.evaluate(AndExpression.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.changed(EvaluationReference.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService$1.changed(EvaluationService.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService.handleSelectionChanged(SelectionService.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService.lambda$0(SelectionService.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$1.run(SelectionAggregator.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator.notifyListeners(SelectionAggregator.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$5.lambda$0(SelectionAggregator.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.RunAndTrack.runExternalCode(RunAndTrack.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$5.changed(SelectionAggregator.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionServiceImpl.setSelection(SelectionServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.selectionChanged(CompatibilityPart.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$1.run(Viewer.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.fireSelectionChanged(TextViewer.java:2621)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.selectionChanged(TextViewer.java:2600)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.setSelectedRange(TextViewer.java:2287)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.DefaultTextDoubleClickStrategy.doubleClicked(DefaultTextDoubleClickStrategy.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer$TextDoubleClickStrategyConnector.getPreviousOffset(TextViewer.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledTextListener.handleEvent(StyledTextListener.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1512)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1520)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1324)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.sendWordBoundaryEvent(StyledText.java:8401)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getWordPrevious(StyledText.java:5508)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getWordPrevious(StyledText.java:5482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleMouseDown(StyledText.java:6193)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.lambda$1(StyledText.java:5796)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1512)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1520)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1324)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4229)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3839)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
```

When I looked for solutions, I found others stumbling across a similar problem but with a different library. The solution was to simply update the library.
The eclipse update-site from key is broken, so I can not update my project. My current Key-Eclipse version is 1.0.0

Comment: maybe you should check where org.key_project.keyide.ui.isGoal is defined and in that plugin (maybe org.key_project.keyide.ui) can be activated and if not why not.
you should also check where org.key_project.keyide.ui.isGoal is used and if you can remove it from there

Comment: I am not even using the isGoal method. My Project won't start, because the dependency (org.key_project.keyide.ui) has a syntax error. It's strange, because I downloaded the latest key from GitHub and there is no org.key_project.keyide.ui.isGoal. Could only find de.uka.ilkd.key.core.isGoal and de.uka.ilkd.key.proof.isGoal.

Comment: search inside org.key_project.keyide.ui/plugin.xml (or however the plugin is called) for isGoal

Comment: The plugin is activated from what I understood. Here is the [file](https://git.key-project.org/key-public/key/-/blob/stable/KeYIDE/src/plugins/org.key_project.keyide.ui/plugin.xml#L274) directly from key_project repo.

Comment: anything else in error log

Comment: Indeed I found another error. I edited the question for that

Comment: thew question would be: is the class there or can it not be loaded for e.g. static init failing

Comment: or can org.key_project.javaeditor be activated?

Comment: My bad. I had the package JMLEditing which contains the org.key_project.javaeditor installed from a locale repository and the other key plugins from remote. Once I used the remote JMLEditing, the 2nd error disappeared. However, the main problem (No property tester contributes a property org.key_project.keyide.ui.isGoal...) stayed.

Comment: you should really check the plugin.xmls where this is coming from and why the property tester class cannot be found

Comment: maybe remote debugging into TypeExtensionManager.getProperty( will help